# ESP8266 doesn't accept AT Commands anymore

Tags: arduino, esp8266, pureftpd

So recently I've been working on some kind of project that uses arduino and esp8266 to make an HTTP get request from a basic website that I created. But somehow I messed things up while sending AT commands using the arduino Serial monitor. Now I doesn't accept any AT command and as soon as I open the Serial monitor I always get this message :

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 19 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 13:29. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
```

I'm just want to be able to communicate with it using its AT commands again .

Any help would be much appreciated  :)

Comment: It's just an empty arduino code :    void setup () {} void loop () {}   . And I connected  the Tx of the esp8266 to the Tx of the arduino and the Rx to Rx

Comment: Did you do sth like: `AT+SAVETRANSLINK` ?

Comment: No I don't know this command.

Comment: First: You have connect Rx with Tx and Tx with Rx. Second: Dont connect the Tx of your arduino without a voltage divider with your rx of the esp. The 5V serial signal of your arduino will destroy your esp.